# error while installing mupdf

Tags: git, glfw, mupdf

I am installing mupdf on centos 6.5, I ran these git commands 
    `git clone git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git` and `git submodule update --init`

These ran successfully. But in the command

```
make prefix=/usr/local install
```

I get an error saying

```
thirdparty/glfw/src/x11_platform.h:38:33: error: X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h: No such file or directory
thirdparty/glfw/src/x11_platform.h:47:37: error: X11/extensions/Xinerama.h: No such file or directory.
```

I tried installing the package  libXcursor-1.1.14-2.1.el6.src.rpm  from here http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/79/size/324562/name/libXcursor-1.1.14-2.1.el6.src.rpm, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the packages directly from the repository

```
sudo dnf install libXcursor libXcursor-devel libXinerama libXinerama-devel
```